# Change colour gradient of div acording to the colour scheme of the image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

**WHAT I HAVE**

I have background image with width and height equal to 100% at `z-index:0`. Now there is another div (`#blanket`) on top of that with equal height and width and has an opacity level of 0.7 to create a blur sort of effect of the image behind it ... The colour of the the div (`#blanket`) is set to white so the it looks like there is 70% percent white transparent sheet behind which is an image.

**WHAT I WANT**

Can I change or set the colour gradient of the div (`#blanket`) that matches the colours in the image behind it .. I first saw that in iphone the way they matched their homescreen theme according to the wallpaper. So if the wallpaper had a red and black sports car then the theme would mostly consist of two basic colours , the red and the black. Can I achieve this in my website. If So then how?

Comment: It is not very clear what you are asking. Is it about dynamically altering the overlay or applying some filter?

Comment: @Shikkediel  dynamically changing the blanket div's gradient according to dynamically changing images in the background

Comment: Hey, I just realised I've responded to your question on CSS-tricks as well. In any case, JavaScript would your friend here. Please add some code, I read there is a pseudo element interfering somehow.

Comment: @Shikkediel where ?? link ??

Comment: My bad, reading too many forum posts. Looked very similar but it's not the same. :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that css filters will help you more in this case. You can choose one from this:

- blur()
- brightness()
- contrast()
- drop-shadow()
- grayscale()
- hue-rotate()
- invert()
- opacity()
- sepia()
- url() - for applying SVG filters

Examples can be found [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/filter/).

Comment: It didn't do exactly what I asked but it gave me an idea that how can we create the similar effect .. thanks